# Idea's for balancing out a HDFS -> HBase map reduce job

Tags: performance, configuration, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

For a client, I've been scoping out the short-term feasibility of running a Cloudera flavor hadoop cluster on AWS EC2.  For the most part the results have been expected with the performance of the logical volumes being mostly unreliable, that said doing what I can I've got the cluster to run reasonably well for the circumstances.

Last night I ran a full test of their importer script to pull data from a specified HDFS path and push it into Hbase.   Their data is somewhat unusual in that the records are less then 1KB's a piece and have been condensed together into 9MB gzipped blocks.  All total there are about 500K text records that get extracted from the gzips, sanity checked, then pushed onto the reducer phase.

The job runs within expectations of the environment ( the amount of spilled records is expected by me ) but one really odd problem is that when the job runs, it runs with 8 reducers yet 2 reducers do 99% of the work while the remaining 6 do a fraction of the work.

My so far untested hypothesis is that I'm missing a crucial shuffle or blocksize setting in the job configuration which causes most of the data to be pushed into blocks that can only be consumed by 2 reducers.  Unfortunately the last time I worked on Hadoop, another client's data set was in 256GB lzo files on a physically hosted cluster.

To clarify, my question; is there a way to tweak a M/R Job to actually utilize more available reducers either by lowering the output size of the maps or causing each reducer to cut down the amount of data it will parse. Even a improvement of 4 reducers over the current 2 would be a major improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are getting hotspots in your reducers. This is likely because a particular key is very popular. What are the keys as the output of the mapper?

You have a couple of options here:

- Try more reducers. Sometimes, you get weird artifacts in the randomness of the hashes, so having a prime number of reducers sometimes helps. This will likely not fix it.
- Write a custom partitioner that spreads out the work better.
- Figure out why a bunch of your data is getting binned into two keys. Is there a way to make your keys more unique to split up the work?
- Is there anything you can do with a combiner to reduce the amount of traffic going to the reducers?

Comment: I will need to dig through the client's reference Map/Reduce application but I think (hope) the keying issue might be the culprit.  It takes about half a hour to bring up the cluster and let it stablize (namenode safemode, etc), then a few more hours to run/test/verify but I will get back to with an answer check if that turns out to be it.

Comment: Ended up writing a quick custom M/R to figure things out.  The client's import is using a identity reducer ( stock from hbase mapreduce package without extension ) and there is in fact only 2 values for their primary key. Otherwise the cardinality of all other values in the record are either binary or equal to the total record set.  I know this is a another question, but do you know if the default hbase import classes can aggregate disparate keys into reduce tasks?